# Android surfaceview camera

Tags: android, camera, android-permissions, surfaceview

I have loaded camera in surfaceview. But during first time APK installation, after asking the runtime permissions the app shows black screen instead of camera preview. But in the second usage of app, the camera preview works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your camera after the permission has been granted, or if the permission is granted.

```
// Activity

    // pseudocode
    void onCreate {
        if (permissionGranted) {
            // setup camera
        } else {
            // ask permission and do setup camera at onRequestPermissionsResult
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        // do your camera setup here
    }
```